# bash script systemctl enable service as non root user on CentOS7

Tags: bash, service, startup, centos7

I have created a script that deploys java programms that have to run on startup. I wrote a litte template that is customised by the script and adds it into /etc/systemd/system/ServerName.service

```
[Unit]
Description= ServerName Java Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin/java -jar PathToFile.jar 
User=psadmin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target # Similar to runlevel 5
```

I have added the user psadmin in visudo to run systemctl without beeing promted for the password. This works pretty fine for starting the service with sudo systemctl start ServerName.service. Then the script reloads the systemctl daemon, "sudo systemctl daemon-reload".

When the script executes the part with systemctl enable ServerName.service, I get in return "Failed to issue method call:Access denied".

When I do this by hand under the same user context I get in return "Failed to issue method call: Invalid argument", but it works and the service is enabled.
Thanks for any hints!

Comment: The problem was the database the java client uses. DB was not running when the service tried to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Systemctl is protected from non-privileged users. You will have to modify sudoers to allow this user or a group (that the user is a part of) to execute the command.

Also this is a better question for ServerOverflow most likely.
See the manpage for sudo

```
%wheel = /usr/bin/systemctl restart ServerName.service
%wheel = /usr/bin/systemctl stop ServerName.service
%wheel = /usr/bin/systemctl start ServerName.service 
%wheel = /usr/bin/systemctl status ServerName.service
```

Comment: How add chance to execute stop/start/restart whithout enter password?